# Method inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing within Unity 2018 and have made a script for decreasing a character's health on collision with an enemy:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static int currentHealth;
    public Slider healthBar;

    void Awake()
    {
        healthBar = GetComponent<Slider> ();
        currentHealth = 100;
    }

    void ReduceHealth()
    {
        currentHealth = currentHealth - 1;
        healthBar.value = currentHealth;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        healthBar.value = currentHealth;
    }
}
```

When I try to use said method in the scripting file for the enemy I get an error stating "Assets/Custom Scripts/BeetleScript.cs(46,28): error CS0122: `HealthManager.ReduceHealth()' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

The following is the enemy script initiating the variables being used and calling the method:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BeetleScript : MonoBehaviour
{

Animator animator;
public GameObject cucumberToDestroy;
public bool cherryHit = false;
public float smoothTime = 3.0f;
public Vector3 smoothVelocity = Vector3.zero;
public PointsManager _ptsManager;
public HealthManager _healthManager;

void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (cherryHit)
    {

        var cm = GameObject.Find("CucumberMan");
        var tf = cm.transform;
        this.gameObject.transform.LookAt(tf);

        // move towards Cucumber Man
        animator.Play("Standing Run");

        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, tf.position,
            ref smoothVelocity, smoothTime);
    }
}

// Collision Detection Test
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {

        _healthManager = GameObject.Find
        ("Health_Slider").GetComponent<HealthManager>();
        _healthManager.ReduceHealth();

        if (!cherryHit)
        {

            BeetlePatrol.isAttacking = true;

            var cm = GameObject.Find("CucumberMan");
            var tf = cm.transform;
            this.gameObject.transform.LookAt(tf);

            animator.Play("Attacking on Ground");
            StartCoroutine("DestroySelfOnGround");
        }
        else
        {
            animator.Play("Standing Attack");
            StartCoroutine("DestroySelfStanding");
        }
    }  

 }
}
```

Any help to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Make the methods, public, they're private by default so change `void ReduceHealth()` to `public void ReduceHealth()`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen this is not a comment. This is an answer. You should write it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your methods are `private`.
You have to write `public` in front of the method you want to access from outside the class.

```
public void ReduceHealth()
{
...
}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot haha, don't know how I missed that. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make void ReduceHealth() to be public -> public void ReduceHealth()